# como receber uma falha de conexão caso o update não for bem sucedido?

Tags: php

Digamos que eu tenha um botão de fazer update no banco.

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE $tabela set algo='$algo' WHERE id=1);

if ($query) {
    echo "sucesso";
} else {
    echo 'falha';
}
```

para verificar se a query foi cadastrada no banco com sucesso (se não deu erro na conexão (por ex: a conexão caiu) ou se houve algum erro no update) eu faço o procedimento acima?

Comment: Isso ai já resolve o problema. Ou tem algum outro problema, além de usar funções obsoletas.

Answer (score 0):

Com o [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) você consegue ver quantos registros foram afetados.

Se for zero, o update não deu certo.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

/* Atualiza os registros */
mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET used=1 WHERE id < 10");
printf ("Registros atualizados: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```